# Java Random Class output 1 or 0

Tags: java, random

The result is pretty impressive. with almost 50% each, however the process is the one I am worried about. Sometime i get 10 ones in a roll or 8 zeros in a roll. Which I consider at that period is not a TRUE randomness. I would want to avoid that and only allowing most 3 repeated sequence. Is there a good advice on this?

```
    int resetOne = 0;
    int resetZero = 0;
    Random ran = new Random();
    while (y < 100) {
        y++;
        x = ran.nextInt(2);
        if (x == 1) {
            resetOne++;
            resetZero = 0;
            if (resetOne == 3) {
                x = ran.nextInt(2);
            }
            oneCounter++;

        } else if (x == 0) {
            resetZero++;
            resetOne = 0;
            if (resetZero == 3) {
                x = ran.nextInt(2);
            }
            zeroCounter++;
        }

        System.out.println(x);
        System.out.println("0 = " + zeroCounter + " " + "1 = " + oneCounter);
    }
```

Comment: That's why it's called **random**.

Comment: only _Sometimes_ right? whatever output you get, it still generated randomly. if you want to change it, then you don't call it _random_ anymore

Answer (score 2):

True randomness could come up 1 10,000 times in a row. It wouldn't be *likely* to, but it could. So I would strongly suggest recalibrating your expectations.

If you really want biased randomness -- a progressively less "fair" coin flip -- you'll need to implement that yourself by tracking recent results and adjusting your probabilities.

Comment: if this case is so called biased randomness, how about having that biased randomness to maintain at 48-52% ratio rate

Comment: Just keep taking random numbers, and it will eventually average out to 50%. The definition of random is that past results do not predict future events. And in fact, since this is only pseudorandom you're unlikely to get especially long runs of one or the other. So the right answer, if you really want random, is to simply stop worrying about it.

Answer (score 1):

As a note before my answer, if I can predict what the next number will be, it's not actually random. In your case, if I get three 0's in a row, I know with 100% certainty that the next number will be a 1.

Now, the simplest way to implement what you're asking is just to introduce two new variables: a counter that gets reset when the result changes, and a cache of the last returned value. If the counter is at the maximum allowed in a row for a result (you got three 0's in a row), then just return the other number and reset the counter (and store this returned value in the lastReturned cache).

This should keep your distributions close to the 50% mark, since it should happen approximately equally for 1s and 0s. It should be easy to test it out to verify.

Comment: does this mean recalling the random function, and have a chance to get a 4th 0s?

Comment: As an example, it gets called three times and returns three 0's (through the randomness) - the fourth time it gets caught by the threshold and automatically returns a 1 (no need to repeatedly ask `Random` until you get a 1 since it's the only other result - return it and reset the counter. Next time you call the function it will delegate to `Random` again, and may return a 1 (increment the counter), or 0 (reset the counter)

Comment: just edited my code to your implementation, the rate of constancy has been reduced to 6